# Is there an elegant way to iterate over index and one column of a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'd like have a loop that iterates over both the index, and the entries in one specific column of a dataframe. I've found a solution that works, but I feel there should be something more elegant. Any suggestions?

Working example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(index = [10, 20, 30])
df['A'] = [1, 2, 3]
df['B'] = [5, 7, 9]

# This is the part that feels like it could be more elegant
for i, v in zip(df.index, df['A']):
    print(i, v)
```

Comment: And why do you want to iterate? What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have a dataframe where the index is timestamps, each column corresponds to a chemical, and each entry in each column (each "cell") is a list of replicate measurements. I want to calculate mean and standard deviation for each of these lists, and plot them as a function of time. This was my original intention, and my solution used `zip` as shown above, but of course with some additional logic in place of the print function. But then, I felt that there ought to be a more elegant way of doing this, and thus my intentions shifted to finding an answer to the question above.

Comment: As to why I want to iterate, it is not that I originally wanted to iterate, but I just thought that would be a sensible approach. But now I'm wondering if I mightn't have achieved what I was originally trying to do (calculating mean and standard deviation of each of the column entries where each entry is a list, and plotting as a function of the index) without iteration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dataframe entry has a dictionary interface for this purpose. You can do `df['A'].items()`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(index=[10, 20, 30])
df['A'] = [1, 2, 3]
df['B'] = [5, 7, 9]

for i, v in df['A'].items():
    print(i, v)
```

```
10 1
20 2
30 3
```